# Oscillating hazelcast instance

Tags: hazelcast

I have a concern. I have 3 instances of some service that is using Hazelcast Map. All instances are using map with sync backup strategy.

What will happen if one instance will start going up and down (Oscillating) each second (due to network issues)?

Could this slowdown all map operations for all instances? Or Hazelcast could somehow blacklist such instance?

Answer (score 1):

Typically when a node joins/exits it is due to failure of heartbeats. This can be caused by numerous issues such as half open socket. Yes performance is negatively impacted since as a node joins or leaves the map data is migrated.

You may want to enable Ping Failure Detector, but identifies the failures on OSI Layer 3 (Network Layer). This detector is by default disabled. Here is how to configure the failure detector: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#failure-detector-configuration